# Copying a .bin input file into linux

Tags: c++, linux

I need to take a provided .bin file as input, convert it to string representations, and do a bunch of other fun stuff.  The issue is that we are being graded on the school's linux server which I have almost no idea how to use.

On the Linux machine I have created a directory for my program called "read".  Inside is my "read.cpp" file.  I'm guessing the .bin need to go in this directory, since "read.cpp" utilizes it as input, but I have no clue how I can get it there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a programming problem at this point., so https://superuser.com/ may be a better place to ask this. That said, see if you can use `scp` or `sftp` to move the file. Since you're coming in from non-unix and probably Windows, a tool like filezilla may help

Comment: You might want to start with a basic linux tutorial like [http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/](this one) or [http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_learning_the_shell.php](this one).  Once you've educated yourself a bit, come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Also useful is to write the program on a development system you are familiar with, and then move it to the Linux server when done. Make sure you use only Standard C++ library calls and you should have few problems porting from your PC to the server.

Comment: I actually am coding everything in Visual Studio, which I know quite well.  The Prof gave us code that uses functions not supported, so I need to copy and paste into linux to compile unfortunately.  Then only issue is dealing with a .bin :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using WinSCP to transfer the file.  Makes it super easy.  I've used it before and completely forgot it was a thing.  Cheers!